# How to point a pointer to a character

Tags: c++, pointers, character

So i want to point a pointer to a character and then output the address put it outputs this weird thing: t+ a. Any help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

char a = 't';
char* p = &a;

cout << p;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ? Is there any error ? Whats do you expect ? Your post is incomplete, we cannot help you.

Comment: Output either `cout << (void*)p;` or `cout << *p;`, depends upon what you want to see.

Comment: I want to see the address of that character

Comment: Just to add the proper C++ cast would be `static_cast<const void*>(p)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing a `char*` type, which the `cout` tries to interpret as a string.

Print the value of the pointer (The **address** it points to) using:

```
cout << (void *)p;
-- OR --
cout << static_cast<void *>(p);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `char *` is conventionally not just used as a pointer to a `char`, but a pointer to a [null-terminated C-string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) instead. [`cout` will then print all the characters pointed to by `p` until it finds a `'\0'`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), so you get to see the `t` and then it prints invalid memory which is undefined behavior which may crash or print garbage or something else.

The way to fix this is to use `void *` or maybe `const void *` instead which is just a pointer with an address but no type information attached. `void *p = &a;` would be one fix. `void *p2 = p;` and then using `std::cout << p2;` would be another. You can also use a cast as shown in the other answer, except you should be using a C++ cast like `static_cast<const void*>(p)` instead of a C cast like `(void *)p` because once you get used to them they become easier to read and reason about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want address of the pointer, either cast it to void pointer

```
std::cout << (void *)p;
```

or use `printf` with %p option

```
printf("%p", p);
```

Otherwise it will be treated as null terminated string, which it is not.